# Find tables which contain a certain column in an Access database?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to find specified column named `deals` in large number of tables that exist in my database by using the below SQL query in VBA.

```
   fndtble = "SELECT DISTINCT " & _
   "TABLE_NAME As tblname FROM " & _
   "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'deals'"
```

I'm getting this runtime error:

> 3024 couldn't find file INFORMATION_SCHEMA.mdb

Any idea to solve this error?

Comment: MS Access does not support `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

Comment: Is there any way to a find a table which contains specified column name in access

Comment: Yes, but not with Access SQL.

Comment: have a look at the [TableDefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243648%28v=office.12%29.aspx) collection. Enumerate it to list all tables. Then use the TableDef for each table to lookup for the field in its Fields collection. Example's [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177463%28v=office.12%29.aspx)